# java 6 vs. java 7 string.matches with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url, gxt

I am having an issue with a url validator when I use string.matches(regex).  The following was working in Java 6 but is not working in Java 7.

```
regex = "^http[s]?://(([^/:\\.[:space:]]+(\\.[^/:\\.[:space:]]+)*)|([0-9](\\.[0-9]{3})))(:[0-9]+)?((/[^?#[:space:]]+)(\\?[^#[:space:]]+)?(\\#.+)?)?$"
```

This code is on the client side using GWT/GXT to validate the user input before sending it off to the server side.

Puzzling to say the least.

This is the method:

```
public boolean validateURL(String url) {
    return ((url != null) && url.matches(VALID_URL_REGEX));
}
```

where VALID_URL_REGEX is equal to the regex above

Here is the code that calls the validateURL method:

```
    this.serverUrlTextField.addValidator(new AbstractValidator<String>() {
        @Override
        public List<EditorError> validate(Editor<String> field, String value) {
            String url = serverUrlTextField.getText();
            if (!Util.validateURL(url)) {
                okButton.setEnabled(false);
                return createError(new DefaultEditorError(field, INVALID_URL, value));
            }
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input for us to check?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that everything in Java 7 comes back as an error.

Comment: @TungPham Can you post a sample code that works in Java 6 and causes an error with Java 7 (with input, method call etc.) so we can reproduce it?

Comment: the URL textfield has auto validate set to true.  http://yahoo.com failed

Comment: @TungPham Until you show the code you are running it is going to be difficult to get an answer...

Comment: This is the method: public boolean validateURL(String url) { return ((url != null) && url.matches(VALID_URL_REGEX)); } where VALID_URL_REGEX is equal to the regex in original post

Comment: Here is the code that calls the validateURL method:        this.serverUrlTextField.addValidator(new AbstractValidator<String>() {
            @Override
            public List<EditorError> validate(Editor<String> field, String value) {
                String url = serverUrlTextField.getText();
                if (!Util.validateURL(url)) {
                    okButton.setEnabled(false);
                    return createError(new DefaultEditorError(field, INVALID_URL, value));
                }
                okButton.setEnabled(true);
                return null;
            }
        });

Comment: Please put code in your question, it is much more readable than in a comment.

Comment: Your  regexp does not seem very robust. Plus it requires an http prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GXT has a special class `com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp` that is more compatible with JavaScript. I've also modified the regex in a way that should work in JavaScript.

```
String p = "^(http[s]?://)?(([^/:\\.\\s]+(\.[^/:\\.\\s]+)*)|([0-9](\\.[0-9]{3})))(:[0-9]+)?((/[^?#\\s]+)(\\?[^#\\s]+)?(\\#.+)?)?$";
RegExp r = RegExp.compile(p, "i");
String url = serverUrlTextField.getText();
if (!r.test(url)) {
    okButton.setEnabled(false);
    return createError(new DefaultEditorError(field, INVALID_URL, value));
}
okButton.setEnabled(true);
return null;
```

Comment: I tried that but the java.net.URI is not supported in GXT.  The code gets compiled and the GXT java code get compiled to javascripts for use in a web browser.

Comment: @tphamcc - OK, just making sure. If you are using GXT then you should be using `com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp`.